# finding closest values in two arrays without repetitions

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 arrays `list1` and `list2`

```
list1 = np.array([1052, 1092, 1117,1135, 1156,1212,1249,1325,1363,1380,1382,1400,1484])
list2 = np.array([1053.435, 1093.698, 1118.342, 1136.697,
                  1157.832, 1212.938, 1215.741, 1250.266, 1252.352,
                  1254.453, 1256.831, 1259.182, 1326, 1367.228,
                  1400, 1410, 1740])
```

for each element in `list1` I would like to find the closest element in `list2` and return its index.

```
mylist = []
for idxlabel in range(0,len(list1)): 
    a = min(enumerate(list2), key=lambda x:abs(x[1]-list1[idxlabel]))
    print a
    mylist.append(np.copy(a))
```

My problem is that after that one element in `list2` is found as "best match" I would like to remove it from the search to avoid that different element in `list1` match with the same element in `list2`

```
(0, 1053.4349999999999)
(1, 1093.6980000000001)
(2, 1118.3420000000001)
(3, 1136.6969999999999)
(4, 1157.8320000000001)
(5, 1212.9380000000001)
(7, 1250.2660000000001)
(12, 1326.0)
(13, 1367.2280000000001)
(13, 1367.2280000000001)
(13, 1367.2280000000001)
(14, 1400.0)
(15, 1410.0)
```

In this example indeed the the 9th 10th and 11th elements of list1 match all with the 13th element of `list2` and this is NOT desired...

Comment: can we discard the `lambda`?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder yes sure, this is just a piece of code I found to find the closest match... feel free to do it in another way

Comment: edited example..

Comment: `np.searchsorted(list2, list1)` is probably a good starting point (if indeed they are sorted)

Comment: Hi @JonClements I get as well repeated index with np.serachsorted

Comment: That's why I said it's a *starting point* :)

Comment: @JonClements Searchsorted ends it too :)

Comment: @Divakar the question you pointed me does not answer my question... it also replicates the matches

Comment: @gabboshow Could you add the expected output into the question?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way to do it, but you could keep a copy of that list2 array and modify it every time you find a match. Something like this:

```
list2aux = list(list2)
mylist = []
for idxlabel in range(0,len(list1)): 
    a = min(enumerate(list2aux), key=lambda x:abs(x[1]-list1[idxlabel]))
    list2aux[a[0]] = 0
    print(a)
    mylist.append(np.copy(a))
```

Changing that element in list2aux to 0 will make the values that were already selected as best matches not to be selected again.